# Summing dynamic range of columns

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumifs

I am trying to write formula to sum values of the columns where last column dynamically changes when user selects drop down.

This is example data screenshot:

[image]

This is summary tab screenshot:

[image]

Period is selected from drop down menu. (when Period is selected it changes Cell F3)
Class is selected from drop down menu too.

My `SUMIF` in Cell F4 is:
`=SUMIFS(INDEX(data!$D:$K,,MATCH($B$2,data!$D$1:$K$1,0)),data!$B:$B,$D4,data!$A:$A,$B$5)`

What I am trying to achieve now is to calculate sum of periods P1 and up to selected period. For example P4

I have uploaded test spreadsheet to google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NczIxxIXGVdAIpTfOTr7ys8BCOFh_RJj/view?usp=sharing

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have O365 with the `FILTER` and `SEQUENCE` functions, you can use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(
             FILTER(data!$D:$K,
                      (data!$B:$B=$D4)*
                      (data!$A:$A=$B$5)),
              SEQUENCE(COUNTIFS(data!$A:$A,$B$5,data!$B:$B,$D4)),
              SEQUENCE(,MATCH($B$2,data!$D$1:$K$1,0))))
```

If you have an earlier version of Excel, try:

```
=SUM(
     INDEX(data!$D:$K,
             AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((data!$B:$B=D4)*(data!$A:$A=$B$5))*ROW($A:$A),
                        ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIFS(data!$A:$A,$B$5,data!$B:$B,D4)))),
             TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,
                        MATCH($B$2,data!$D$1:$K$1))))))
```

*The latter formula may need be confirmed as an **array formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.*

[image]